# JAWS cannot read out the "live region" on SWT Accessibility Snippet. How can I force JAWS to read that region?

Tags: java, swt, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

I tried the SWT Accessibility Snippet called `declare a message area to be a "live region"` [Here is a link](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet363.java)

But the JAWS doesn't read out the "live region" text and the refreshable braille display doesn't show anything. The NVDA reads out the text but the braille display doesn't show anything.

How can I force JAWS to read out the text? (I cannot let the text has the focus because it is a label.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a known limitation of live regions - they do not get represented on Braille displays. What is your use case? If its a label, why does the user not simply go to the input field to find the information? Why do you need to use live regions?

Comment: I try to develop an assistant software that guide the blind user through the process. I use the live region to give the next instruction for the user. The steps can be varied depending on the assignments. I don't know what else can suit my need. I am open for every suggestion. Thank you!

PS: I tried this [snippet](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet340.java) and it works for 2 or 3 loops and then not anymore. How can I update the Control information and inform the screenreader about that?